# How to bring ImageView over the CardView? Please see details

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-xml, android-cardview

I'm developing an app and I have made the below shown layout:

[image: Screenshot with an avatar, name and twitter handle where the name & twitter pane is covering part of the avatar]

There is a `CircleImageView` and a `CardView`.

Here's the XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.playrapp.playr.Profile"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_profile">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/profileCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:contentPadding="10dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/userImageProfile"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here, the `CardView` is over the `ImageView`. I want `ImageView` to be over the `CardView`. How can I do that?

Please let me know.

Comment: wrap it in a dummy LinearLayout

Answer (score 42):

Elevation of `CardView` is more higher than `CircleImageView`. So, you have to set higher elevation to `CircleImageView` to show it over `CardVew`.

Set `CardView` elevation as `app:cardElevation="4dp"` and set `CircleImageView` elevation as `android:elevation="8dp"`

**Here is the working XML code. Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/profileCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="false" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
            android:padding="24dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hammad Nasir"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                android:textColor="#727272"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="\@hammadnasir"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textColor="#727272" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/userImageProfile"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:elevation="8dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 2):

The `CardView` has an elevation set by default set `app:elevation="0dp"`in the xml file.

Comment: this did the job, but the cardview doesn't look as a card anymore! :/

Comment: how do you mean? could you share a screenshot?

Comment: Just one question - why do you want to place an image on top of the cardview? Couldn't you just put it inside?

Comment: mam, this layout is of user's profile. I want to develop it like that. What's the default elevation of a cardview?

Comment: I don't know the default value - I'm sorry. But I just had another idea. You could maybe place the imageview inside another cardview (with transparent background). I didn't try it but it could work this way

Comment: the default elevation is 2dp and by setting imageview's elevation as 3dp I got the wanted results. Can you tell me how to specify `android:elevation=""` for API level below 21?

Comment: You can't set an elevation to views below API 21... It's just possible for the `CardView`because it's part of the support lib. That's why I suggested to put the image in a `CardView`

Comment: putting the imageview in another cardview is making it look weird and setting the elevation of the given cardview as 0dp is also making it look weird. :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123287/discussion-between-katharina-and-hammad-nasir).

Answer (score 0):

**CardView -> app:cardElevation ="4dp"
ImageView -> android:translationZ="6dp"**